# Void cannot dereferenced while chaining methods

Tags: java

I am trying to use PrintWriter like this:

```
new PrintWriter("/tmp/test.csv", "UTF-8")
   .println("1,1,1")
   .close();
```

But Java complains:

> Void cannot dereferenced

If I do:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("/tmp/test.csv", "UTF-8");
pw.println("1,1,1");
pw.close();
```

It works, any reasons?

Comment: "Void cannot dereferenced" - you're missing a word there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The signature of the [`PrintWriter.println(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-java.lang.String-) (and the other `println` methods) return `void` (not a `PrintWriter`). You can't chain calls to `void` methods.

Comment: aww! they could return PrintWriter

Comment: @gio They could have, but they did not.

Answer (score 2):

`PrintWriter.println` doesn't return anything, so you are calling `close` on `void`(i.e *nothing*), not on a `PrintWriter` object.

Answer (score 2):

[println](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintWriter.java#PrintWriter.println%28%29) source. As you can see it's a public void.

For the daisy chaining to actually work, it would have to be

```
public PrintWriter println(char x) {
      synchronized (lock) {
             print(x);
             println();
         }
         return this;
     }
```

for all the different types of accepted arguments 
When nothing is returned, then chaining is not possible.

You could extend the printwriter, and make your own chainable methods.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply `close()` to `println()`. Only to the object itself. So instead of `a.println().close();` use `a.println(); a.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a reason. the `println` method does not return a result.